# Spring Transaction Management - AspectJ - Compile time loading - Sample

Tags: spring-boot, aspectj

I would like to implement transaction management in spring boot 2 application using aspectj mode. I would like to go with compile time loading.

Can any one please provide me sample code?

Comment: Stack overflow is not a place to ask for people to do your work for you. Before asking a question, you should show that you have done your research, tried some code and are not able to get things to work. You should never ask for someone to do your work for you. What have you already done? This question has been answered. Have you even searched?  What specifically do you need help with? Did you RTFM?

Comment: Please find my answer below. Sorry that I had asked for code sample.

Answer (score 0):

Transaction management using aspectj is done by weaving transaction semantics either during compile time or load time.
The below example is done during compile time. Versions are not mentioned below as spring boot already manages it.

Annotate your persistence config as below. We need to set the transaction mode to be aspects

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement(mode = AdviceMode.ASPECTJ)
public class YourPersistenceConfig {
}
```

### Maven Configuration

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>    
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.11</version>
            <configuration>
                <sources>
                    <source>
                        <basedir>${project.basedir}</basedir>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*.java</include>
                        </includes>
                    </source>
                </sources>      
                <aspectLibraries>
                    <aspectLibrary>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
                    </aspectLibrary>
                </aspectLibraries>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugin>
</build>
```

Comment: Enable trace level in the log for package "org.springframework.transaction". You will be able to see transaction start and end.